# whats wrong with this code of reading with mmap?

Tags: c, mmap

I am trying to run this code, while I am ending with -
value: 1 
value: 0.000000

My question is why the both results are different??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main ()
{
int fd;
struct stat mystat;
void *pmap;
int i,integer;
double *values;
int32_t *mapped_baseA;
int32_t fdA;


fd = open("test.txt",O_RDWR); // a text file containing- 1 2 3 4 5
if(fd==-1)
{
perror("open");
exit(1);
}

if(fstat(fd,&mystat)<0)
{
perror("fstat");
close(fd);
exit(1);
}

pmap =  mmap(0,mystat.st_size,PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,fd,0);
if(pmap==MAP_FAILED)
{
perror("mmap failed");
close(fd);
exit(1);
}

//strncpy(pmap,"That is my name",15);
sscanf (pmap, " %d", &integer);
printf("value: %d \n", integer);
```

//printing the values after scanning from string.

```
values = (double *) mmap(0,mystat.st_size,PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,fd,0);

printf("value: %lf \n", values[1]);
```

//printing the values from pointer
    munmap (pmap, mystat.st_size);

```
close(fd);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `a text file containing- 1 2 3 4 5`will not yield doubles automatically when mmap()ed. It will occur to the program as a (large) char array. AND: you should take care of rounding up the mmapped size up to a page boundery. (and ignoring the rounded-up part)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read carefully (and *several* times) [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html). Notice:

> A file is mapped in multiples of the page size.

and in the `ERRORS` section

> `EINVAL`    We don't like addr, length, or offset (e.g., they are too
>                 large, or not aligned on a page boundary).

Consider also using [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) on your executable.

Of course, a memory mapping is just giving a view (as raw sequence of *bytes*) of the mapped file into the [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) by modifying its [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space). It obviously won't do any conversion (you might use [sscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html) or [strtol(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) on parts of that view to make such a conversion from an UTF8 or ASCII string representation of a number into its machine representation).

Comment: I did this only to see the results error. Only the mmap with type cast to double is required, other can be deleted.

Comment: I just want to map a file which is having 1 2 3 4 5 inside it to a variable "values".  but its returning 0.0000 on printing. why?